# How to Add or Inject Columns to jQuery Datatable using aoColumns?

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm currently trying to dynamically add a Column of Data to a jQUery Datatable.

Essentially when a user clicks on a UI component (Data Viz/Chart), it should inject a new column of data into the datatable.

I am trying to do this by pushing the column information into datatable.fnSettings().aoColumns then re-rendering the datatable.

But I am getting an error.

Here is what my code looks like:

> This is part of an extensive feature on a dashboard
>   in which the tables are integrated with C3.js + DC.js + Crossfilter.JS

Here is my HTML for the Table:

```
<table id="dc-data-table" class="list table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Age</th>
       <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Below is the Javascript that renders the table in respect to the DC and Crossfilter Aspects.

RefreshTable() will redraw the table if the user filters the dataset using a DC chart with Crossfilter... Essentially the dataset changes and then

> datatable.fnClearTable(); datatable.fnAddData(newdataset);
>   datatable.fnDraw();

is applied to update the Datatable.

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var all = ndx.groupAll();

var tabledim = ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.name});

dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count")
  .dimension(ndx)
  .group(all);

  var datatable = $("#dc-data-table").dataTable({
      "bSort": true,
      "bInfo": false,
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "bInfo": true,
      "bDeferRender": true,
      "aaData": tabledim.top(Infinity),
      "bDestroy": true,
      "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "name",
              "mRender": function(client) {
                 var res = '<a href="/URL/To/Person/' + client + '/" target="_blank">' + client + '</a>';
            return res;}},
            { "mData": "date_call_rcvd",
              "mRender": function(d) {return dtFormat2(parseDate(d));}},
            { "mData": "age",
              "sDefaultContent": ""},
            { "mData": "gender",
              "sDefaultContent": ""}
          ],
          "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
          "iDisplayLength": 25
  });

  function RefreshTable() {
      dc.events.trigger(function () {
          alldata = tabledim.top(Infinity);
          datatable.fnClearTable();
          datatable.fnAddData(alldata);
          datatable.fnDraw();
          dc.redrawAll();
          d3.selectAll(".pie-slice").call(d3Tip);
          d3.selectAll(".pie-slice").on("mouseover", d3Tip.show)
          .on("mouseout", d3Tip.hide);
          });
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < dc.chartRegistry.list().length; i++) {
      var chartI = dc.chartRegistry.list()[i];
      chartI.on("filtered", RefreshTable);
  };
```

Now I need to inject a new column of data whenever a user interacts with a set of C3.js Charts. This data is already contained within the dataset I am using, but based on what the user clicks, a specific field of data or "keyword" should return from the dataset and then be added to the table.

These are the declarations within an onclick() method on the chart itself and will run after a user clicks on the chart.

```
//First Declare keyword to represent the field that is being added
var keyword = ThisChart.keyword.toString()

//Append Column Name to Table's HTML 
$('#dc-data-table thead tr').append('<th id="keyword_col">'+ keyword +'</th>');

//Access aoColumns from fnSettings and push Column Data object in.
datatable.fnSettings().aoColumns.push({
   "mData": keyword,
   "sDefaultContent": ""
});

//RefreshTable() to update the DataTable
RefreshTable()
```

However this raises an Error

**Uncaught TypeError: oCol.fnGetData is not a function**

Do you have an idea as to what I'm doing wrong? Or perhaps a better way to inject a column into the datatable dynamically using my current setup?

Any advice would be helpful and greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to hack this issue.

Essentially, simply pushing the new field into `aoColumns` from `datatable.fnSettings()` does not update a lot of the elements that are contained within that particular object. You would need to run `datatable = $("#dc-data-table").dataTable()` again to set those required methods/attributes.

I store the essential datatable settings within an object and declare it as a global variable. Then I can make changes to that variable from any method and rewrite the datatables over and over again.

Thus here is my hack:

```
//Define Initial Table

var oTable = {
      "bSort": true,
      "bInfo": false,
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "bInfo": true,
      "bDeferRender": true,
      "aaData": tabledim.top(Infinity),
      "bDestroy": true,
      "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "name",
              "mRender": function(client) {
                 var res = '<a href="/URL/To/Person/' + client + '/" target="_blank">' + client + '</a>';
            return res;}},
            { "mData": "date_call_rcvd",
              "mRender": function(d) {return dtFormat2(parseDate(d));}},
            { "mData": "age",
              "sDefaultContent": ""},
            { "mData": "gender",
              "sDefaultContent": ""}
          ],
          "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
          "iDisplayLength": 25
  };

var datatable = $("#dc-data-table").dataTable(oTable);

//Inject Keyword as new Column then Update

chart.onClick(function(d){
  clearAll();
  $('#dc-data-table thead tr').append('<th id="keyword_col">'+ keyword +'</th>');
  oTable.aoColumns.push({
     "mData": keyword,
     "sDefaultContent": ""
  });
  datatable = $("#dc-data-table").dataTable(oTable);
  RefreshTable();
})

// Clear Function to Remove Column

function clearAll(){
 if(oTable.aoColumns.length > 4){
     oTable.aoColumns.pop();
     datatable = $("#dc-data-table").dataTable(oTable);
 }
 RefreshTable();
 dc.filterAll();
 dc.renderAll();
};
```

I am concerned that this might not be the most efficient solution, perhaps not the fastest way to do this since I am now declaring two global variables and constantly rendering datatables on user clicks. Feel free to suggest a better method, that would be greatly appreciated.